# Where can I get Python 3.4 CNTK Beta 11 Windows whl files?

Tags: python, deep-learning, cntk

The question says it all. Where can I get the whl file?
It is not listed here: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-Windows-Python

Neither

```
pip install https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/GPU/cntk-2.0.beta11.0-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
```

works....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version is Beta 15.0, for which you can find WHL links here (which you have already located as per your post): https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-Windows-Python

If you do want Beta 11.0 specifically, it looks like you will need to use the script-based install which you can find here: http://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/releases

Ian

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise, Python Wheels for Beta 11 are packed together with the correspondent [binary distribution](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/releases/tag/v2.0.beta11.0). Like Ian suggested, the best way is to use installation script. however if you need `whl` files themselves, you will find them inside binary distribution archive, in `cntk/cntk/Python` folder.